# Adapting nested domain interface & bean type hierarchy in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm writing a REST service based on JAX-RS & have hit some trouble with JAXB databinding.

After trying for a number of days, I'm still confused how to adapt between domain objects referencing an interface & an abstract value type hierarchy via JAXB. I've started down the path of leveraging `XmlAdapter`, but have hit a dead end trying to convert between the value type & the domain interface automatically.

**Note**: there are a few company mandates that make this a bit more tricky than I expected: for build artifact dependency isolation, the JAXB annotated beans cannot directly or indirectly reference the domain types (the `XmlAdapter` can; it's in a different build artifact). Similarly, dependency injection & other support frameworks cannot be introduced. Solutions using standard JAXB & JAX-RS would fit my requirements best.

### Domain Types

```
public interface IBar {
    //interface not relevant to this problem
}

public final class Foo {
    private final IBar bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public IBar getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

### JAXB-Mappable Types

```
public abstract class AbstractBarBean {
    //marker base class to help JAXB manage the hierarchy
    //this type contains no interface or fields
}

@XmlRootElement
public final class ExampleBarBean extends AbstractBarBean {
    //implementation not relevant to this problem
    //there will be an unbounded number of these implemented
    //looking to avoid having a unique XmlAdapter for each implementation
}

@XmlRootElement
public final class FooBean {

    @XmlElementRef
    private AbstractBarBean bar;

    public FooBean() { /* no-arg constructor to please jaxb */ }

    public FooBean(AbstractBarBean bar) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public AbstractBarBean getBar() { return bar; }
    public void setBar(AbstractBarBean bar) { this.bar = bar; }
}
```

### FooXmlAdapter

```
public final class FooAdapter extends XmlAdapter<FooBean, Foo> {

    @Override
    public FooBean marshal(Foo v) throws Exception {
       IBar bar = v.getBar();  //can obtain trivially

       //how to marshall to an AbstractBarBean automatically via JAXB??
       AbstractBarBean barBean = jaxbMagicToConvertDomainToMappable(bar);
       return new FooBean(barBean);
    }

    @Override
    public Foo unmarshal(FooBean v) throws Exception {
       AbstractBarBean barBean = v.getBar(); //can obtain trivially 

       //how to unmarshall to an IBar implementation automatically via JAXB??
       IBar bar = jaxbMagicToConvertMappableToDomain(barBean);
       return new Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

As stated in the `XmlAdapter` comments, I'm stuck in the adapter implementation.

How can I leverage JAXB to automatically manage the conversions between `IBar` & `AbstractBarBean` instances?

Is there a way utilize the JAXBContext to convert between the `IBar` & `AbstractBarBean` implementations **without** having to write an `XmlAdapter` implementation for each new `IBar` implementation?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here. You say in your marshall method that you want to marshall to an AbstractBarBean but this makes no sense because the method will marshall an instance of FooBean to an XML file and the other way around. Please, try to be more specific and explain what kind of output you expect to get.

Comment: @dsp_user sure here goes: `XmlAdapters` don't work with XML; they expose user-defined delegation methods JAXB invokes to convert between unmappable types (my domain types), & mappable types (my beans). So the `marshall` method doesn't produce XML; instead it generates an object that is mappable by JAXB. `unmarshall` is the reverse; converts a mappable type to an unmappable domain objects. So outputs are still expected to be the mappable types & domain objects. i'm just stuck inside the `FooXmlAdapter` not sure how to convert between the nested unmappable interfaces to the mappable beans.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification though I'm still not sure that I fully understand. I don't think that it's JAXB responsibility to convert between mappable and unmappable types. Sure, you do extend XmlAdapter but it's you who should write the conversion code in the marshall and unmarshall methods. I don't see how JAXB can do that for you.

Comment: @dsp_user totally agreed & that's precisely where I'm stuck. I don't know how to properly handle the polymorphic conversion between the nested domain interface & nested abstract bean types within my `XmlAdapter`. When not nested within another type, JAXB can handle the conversion without issue. I've confirmed this with integration tests on non-nested instances: JAXB can successfully marshal/unmarshal between `IBar` & `AbstractBarBean` root elements just fine. I'm getting stuck on the polymorphic conversion between `IBar`/`AbstractBarBean` from within the `FooXmlAdapter`.

Comment: I'll try your code when I find the time (probably over the weekend) and let's see what I'll be able to  come up with (if anything)

Comment: If you're just interested in finding out the correct instance types for IBar and AbstractBarBean respectively, then just use something like if(barBean instanceof ExampleBarBean) and if it evaluates to true just call the appropriate constructor on the ExampleBarBean class. The same is true of IBar too.

Comment: unfortunately solutions like this don't pass code review in my company: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html. with an unbounded number of IBar implementations, an explicit switch on type is a maintenance burden at best & breeding ground of bugs in the average case. polymorphic dispatch should be used instead of instanceof checks, but it's not clear how to actually _use_ that approach in this case.